# Auth session data flush after redirect laravel 5.4

Tags: session, authentication, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4 and login user with auth

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
      });
         $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "./post_xing_res",
                     data: {user_data:response},

                     success: function(msg){
                      console.log(msg);
                      if(msg == 1)
                      {
                        location.href='http://192.168.1.12/maulik_proj/studicash_new/public/welcome';
                      } 
                     }
                });
       }
```

as you can see above my ajax call in `post_xing_res` i am using auth as below
$created_at=$updated_at=time();

/*if(Request::ajax()) {*/

```
    $data = Input::all(); 
    $check_acc_first = DB::table('users')
        ->where('login_with',3)
        ->where('xing_id',$data['user_data']['user']['id'])
        ->first();

    if ($check_acc_first) {
        Auth::loginUsingId($check_acc_first->user_id);
        echo "<pre>";print_r(Auth::user());
    }
    else {
        $insert_user = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(
                            array('login_with' => 3, 'xing_id' => $data['user_data']['user']['id'], 'profile_pic' => $data['user_data']['user']['photo_urls']['maxi_thumb'],'first_name' => $data['user_data']['user']['first_name'],'last_name' => $data['user_data']['user']['last_name'],'email' => $data['user_data']['user']['active_email'],'created_at'=>$created_at,'updated_at'=>$updated_at)
                        );

        $user_data = DB::table('users')
                        ->where('user_id',$insert_user)
                        ->get();
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($user_data);
        Auth::loginUsingId($user_data->user_id);
    }
    if (Auth::check()) {

        echo 1;
         exit;
    }
```

as you can see i am able to get user data as well as Auth::user data when print `Auth::user` and getting 1 as response also 
But when i redirect to welcome page `Auth::user` data  returns **blank**
Below is my route file

```
Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {

    Route::post('/post_xing_res','SocialAuthController@postXingRes');

});

    Route::get('/welcome',function(){
        return view('welcome');
    });
```

Can you please help me to get out of this problem
Thanks in advance